# Is there a jquery carousel plugin that supports multiple widths?

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am trying to find a jQuery carousel plugin similar to [JCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) but that supports divs of multiple widths. JCarousel only works if you have a set width and height.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I really like http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/. Here's a page of examples with various width items: http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/examples/variable-visible-variable-size.php

There is also http://matmarquis.com/carousel/ which is responsive right out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I just used [Lemmon's carousel](http://jquery.lemmonjuice.com/plugins/slider-variable-widths.php) and it supports multiple widths :)

[Update Jul 11, 2017]

The link seems to have some problem, but still can find the [Github here](https://github.com/lemmon/Lemmon-Slider).

Answer (score 0):

Lemmon's carousel
http://jquery.lemmonjuice.com/plugins/slider-variable-widths.php
work realy good!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it supports auto width per item:

1. http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/autowidth.html

and the other one, which is more modern and flexible in configuration:

2. https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/